# how to get rid of outer-class reference in xstream output?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I use xstream to marshal an object with nested class to xml string, 
I write this:

```
public static String java2xml(Object obj, Class<?> T) {

    XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
    xstream.processAnnotations(T);
    String xml = xstream.toXML(obj);

    return xml;
}
```

Yet I got a `<outer-class reference="../.."/>` inside the output string.

the object class is:

```
public class Foo {
    private String foocontent;
    private Bar bar;

    // getter and setter


    public class Bar {
        private String blabla;
        // getter and setter
    }

}
```

and I make a `Foo` with this code:

```
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Bar bar = foo.new Bar();
    bar.setBlabla("hello");
    foo.setBar(bar);
    String fooxml = Xutil.java2xml(foo, Foo.class);
    System.out.println(fooxml);
```

and the whole xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<me.mypackage.Foo>
    <bar>
        <blabla>hello</blabla>
        <outer-class reference="../.."/>
    </bar>
</me.mypackage.Foo>
```

Question1: How can I get rid of `outer-class` part?

Question2: how to make a pretty-formatted xml string with xstream?

In the previous post I have much emotional comments and make my question unclear, I edit my post and list the help I'm asking, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `PrettyPrintWriter` to get the pretty format along with a `StringWriter` as follows:

```
public static String java2xml(Object obj, Class<?> T) {
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
    xstream.processAnnotations(T);
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    xstream.marshal(obj, new PrettyPrintWriter(stringWriter));
    return stringWriter.toString();
}
```

As for the `<outer-class reference="../.."/>` issue, if you are not referencing any of `Foo` class members from `Bar` you can get rid of the `<outer-class>` tag by defining the `Bar` class as `static`

Comment: ...you had not add the bar into Foo

Comment: the `Bar` part is the inner class.